# AKKA get common member from extended message trait in receive

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, traits

I'm implementing Pastry protocol with AKKA. Here I defined a trait PastryMessage and several case classes extending this trait as concrete message types.

```
trait PastryMessage{
  val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val destId: NodeId
}
case class Join(destId:NodeId, newbie: ActorRef) extends PastryMessage
case class RoutingTable(destId: NodeId, routingTable: Array[PastryNode]) extends PastryMessage
```

My receive method would be like this

```
def receive = {
  case Join(destId, newbie)=>route(Join(destId, newbie))//and other stuff...
//...
}
```

I have two questions.

1. In the receive method of my actor, how do I get the timestamp of each type of PastryMessage? If I can get it somehow, do I have to write code to get it in every case clause?
2. I want to route the received pastry message to other node, how do I get the original message I received. For the case of a Join message, I think route(Join(destId, newbie)) will create another Join message with different time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can match the Join message as follows to get the timestamp by assigning to a local variable (i.e `msg`), afaik you have to do this kind of matching for all case classes.

```
case msg @ Join(destId, newBie) => {
     println("timeStamp "+msg.timeStamp)
}
```

2. Since you can assign the message to a variable you can forward that to your destination. However shall I ask you what you use this timestamp for? specially in a distributed system timestamps can be varied and inaccurate most of the times. Hope this will help. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew I could assign the message to a local variable. I use timestamp to estimate the travel time cost from one node to another and update the proximity table. Sorry for the late reply.